# Unable to add breakpoint in eclipse+FDT

Tags: eclipse, flash, fdt

i'm using Eclipse 3.7.1 and FDT 3.5 to develop my program, a web game.
now i can build the project and debug it with my Internet Explorer, the Console window prints everything i trace through my codes,but i can not add any breakpoints on the editor gutter,before the line numbers,with double click. and if i right click on the editor gutter,there are only options like "add bookmark" and 'add task",
   i've installed flashplayer_11_ax_debug.
   so what's the problem? i'm very worried about it,'cause my boss is waitting for my work.......
   any help will be expected and respected.thanks a lot guys**

Answer (score 0):

FDT 3.5 is no longer supported and especially with later Eclipse versions (e.g. 3.7.1).

When FDT 3.5 was released, Eclipse was around 3.3 / 3.4. Try downloading a standalone copy of FDT 3.5 or use the FDT 3.5 plugin with an Eclipse based on version 3.3 or 3.4.

You can also upgrade to the latest FDT. The upgrade price isn't much.

http://fdt.powerflasher.com/buy-download/